# Ionic 4 navigation from specific page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-router

I have 5 page (page 1, page 2, page 3, page 4, page 5) and my stack is page1->page2->page3->page4 and i want to move to page 5 from page 2, so my stack stays ( page1-:page2->page5) for this I use 2 lines

```
   await this.navCtrl.navigateBack('page2',{animated: false});
   await this.navCtrl.navigateForward('page5');
```

But this strategy is not good, because the user see the app change for page2 and after to page5.

I would like to improve this code, for de user don't see the change of page, the user just see the page5 and not the page page2.

Any help regarding this would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For Back on page , you can direct code works

`<ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button defaultHref="page2"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>`

and forward page

`constructor(private router:Router){}`

`this.router.navigateByUrl('/page5');`

Comment: Yes, but when I used this approach the user see the animation the app back to page2 and after to pag5, I want to go direct to page5, I see that there is .remove in navController (Ionic 3 )but in ionic 4 navController haven't  kkk, you know other approach ? thanks for the answer